# How to draw an array of NSStrings on as UIView without any leading space between them and occupies the entire rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, drawing

I want to draw an array of strings of varied font size on a UIView as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlzDv.png).I have calculated the height required for each string to be drawn. The array of string in the example is {"Enter some text", "that", "will fit", "the rect"}. I calculate the height as below,

```
    @implementation NSString (Additions)

    - (CGFloat)heightForFont:(UIFont *)font {

    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);

    CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
    CGFloat width = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, &leading);
    CGFloat height = ascent + descent + leading;
    return height;
    }
```

Then I try to draw the string in a UIView as follows:

```
    - (void)drawStringArray:(NSArray *)splittedStringArray  maxYoFString:(CGFloat)maxY rect:(CGRect)rect fontsDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)fontsDict  {
//Alter X origin if scaled
CGFloat originX = rect.origin.x;
CGRect drawRect = rect;
drawRect.origin.x = originX;
drawRect.origin.y = 0.0;
CGFloat heightForString = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < splittedStringArray.count; i++) {
    NSString *string =  splittedStringArray[i];
    UIFont *font = [fontsDict objectForKey:string];
    if(i < splittedStringArray.count -1)
    heightForString =  [string heightForFont:font];
    [string drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{
                                         NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName :self.random.currentTextColor
                                         }];
    drawRect.origin.y += heightForString;
    }
    }
```

But there is always a space that gets added between two lines. I want to draw the string without any leading space.[current image, expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc0KD.png)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to patch the font file itself and fix its line height definitely. Check out how to do it, here.

http://mbauman.net/geek/2009/03/15/minor-truetype-font-editing-on-a-mac/